# Get PID of backround process lauched as other users

Tags: linux, bash, service, pid

I'm trying to store the PID of a background process I need to launch as a non-root user.

When I execute the script below, the PID file is created but stays empty.

```
USER=myuser
PROG=/path/to/service
PROG_ARGS=""
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid 

su $USER -c "python2.7 $PROG $PROG_ARGS &"    
echo $! > $PIDFILE
```

I've tried to place the `&` outside the `su` command like so `su $USER -c "python ..." &`, and it nearly worked since I get a PID but it's always the one  before my actual process (Eg: if my python PID is 3101, the saved PID will be 3100). I suspect this is the PID of the shell that launched the python script.

My question is, how can I launch my python script as a specific user and save the PID at the same time?

I'm running RHLE 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background process is created in the subshell started by `su`, so you need to capture `$!` there.

```
su $USER -c "python2.7 $PROG $PROG_ARGS & echo \$! > $PID_FILE"
```

Comment: Just need to give the permission to write the `PID_FILE` and it worked, Thanks. `chmod o+rw /var/run`